# How to add Twitter4j to Android project

Tags: android

At the moment,I downloaded file twitter4j-android-2.2.5.rar and extracted it..But have many folder and I don't know add which folder and how to add.

Answer (score 2):

Create libs folder and keep your jar file in this folder.Right click on jar choose Build path -> Add to build path.. that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the twitter4j jar file that's in the rar archive to your classpath. If you use Eclipse, it's in project/properties/java build path/libraries, or you can just put it in the libs folder in your project.

Comment: The correct path to the twitter4j core is /twitter4j/libs/twitter-core-XXX. Not the twitter4j rood as specified in the link provided by Christine.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded twitter4j-4.0.2 and the jar file twitter4j-core-4.0.2 is in the lib folder not libs.

twitter4j-4.0.2/lib/twitter-core-4.0.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio,

1. Put the `twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar` file into the `libs` folder.
   (You should see it if you click the `1:Project` tab on the left.
   It is in `<Your Project> > app > libs`.)
2. Right click it and click 'Add as library'

Make sure `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')` is in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'` to your /app/build.gradle dependencies.